# What is a constant reference parameter and how to use it?

Tags: c++

I'm struggling in understanding const when using it with refrence parameter in c++.

I wrote a function that have a constant reference string as a parameter. I passed a string (name) and change it when I called the function.

```
std::string name = "John";

void setName(const std::string& myName){
    name = myName;
}

int main(){
    setName("Jack");
    std::cout << name << std::endl;
}
```

I thought I'll get an error because I'm trying to change the "name" argument witch suppose to be constant as I passed it to the function parameter, but it run without an error and print "Jack". What is const reference parameter is then and what it used for? I thought it use to prevent changing the original variable when it passed to const reference parameter.

Comment: In the example code you show, the variable `myName` in the `setName` function is a reference, but what does it really reference? Note that it *doesn't* reference the global `name` variable, which is a normal mutable and modifiable `std::string` object. So I don't really see the problem here?

Comment: You are not changing the parameter `myName`, you are changing the global `name`. You would get an error if in `setName` you tried changing `myName`.

Comment: `I passed a string (name) and change it when I called the function.` and `I'm trying to change the "name" argument witch suppose to be constant as I passed it to the function parameter`: I don't see this in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not attempt to reassign to `myName`. You are reassigning to global `name`. If you want to prevent changing `name` you should declare that as `const std::string name = "John"`

The `const` parameter will prevent reassignment to `myName` eg:
`myName = "Jeremy"`